# Insert array into the table using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

I have a table with just two columns Id and Name. Where ID is auto incremented primary key. My array may contain couple of hundred items so I dont want to use any loop. My code looks like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
foreach (string item in arrItems)
    dt.Rows.Add(item);

using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, DB2BulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
{   
    bc.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
    bc.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

I have written my code in this way. Is there any way to insert data from array(without creating table)?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that wraps your Array and implements IDataReader. An instance of that class can be passed to the WriteToServer Method of SqlBulkCopy.